# Rails routes to . instead of /

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am writing this question because I didn't find any solution in StackOverflow and/or any related forums. My problem is this basically.

I've added a table called "news" to my Rails project. The table is created exactly in the name "news" in my Mysql.

Following these steps, I encountered a situation that linking to "news" redirects me to "news.1" not "news/1".

My routes.rb

```
match "news" => 'homepage#news'
match "news/:id" => 'homepage#news_details'
```

My controller

```
def news
@news = News.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render layout: "news" } # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @news }
end
end

def news_details
@news = News.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render layout: "news" } # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @users }
end
end
```

in news.html.erb

```
<div class="postDetails">
<a href="trainers-single.html" class="postTitle"><%= news.title %></a>
<p><%= truncate news.details, :length => 90 %></p>
<%= link_to 'MORE INFO', news, :class => "button-small-theme rounded3" %>
</div>
```

In news.html.erb the link_to MORE INFO, news redirects me to "news.1" instead of "news/1"

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing the route as a named route instead.
If you run `rake routes` in a console, see what name it has assigned the route. If it hasn't, then change your routes.rb to

```
match "news/:id", to: "homepage#news_details", as: "show_news"
```

Then in your view, use

```
<%= link_to "MORE INFO", show_news_path(news), class: "button-small-theme rounded3" %>
```

See if that helps.
If not, it may be worth trying to setup your app in a more rails like way. You're accessing your news resources through the `HomepageController` which is alright, but it would be better suited to use a dedicated `NewsController` given you're defining two routes which rails will give you automatically. I'd be more inclined to :

- Create a new controller - `NewsController`
- Add `resources :news` to routes.rb

In your news controller, you should then have something like :

```
class NewsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @news = News.all
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { render layout: "news" }
          format.json { render json: @news }
        end
    end      

    def show
        @news = News.find(params[:id])
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { render layout: "news" }
          format.json { render json: @news }
        end
    end

end
```

Then you just need to move your view files into the `news` folder instead of the `dashboard` folder and it should start working. Then in your view, your link would be the same as you have it now but it should actually work :)

Comment: Your first solution solved everything. Thank you so much! You deserve it.

Comment: Ah awesome :) glad it worked. I always hate getting stuck on something and not knowing why it's not working :(